# Is it possible to automatically serialize object knowing the .class files

Tags: java, serializable

.class files provide blue-prints for each type of object, and Java has rich functionality for extracting the properties of an object, including all of its state.
So why we still need to implement serializable, can we just serialize automatically given the .class files?

Comment: It's not always desirable to allow a class to be serialized. One example is security. If an instance of an object contains a password, we may not want that written to disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Serializable` interface in java is a Marker interface, which has no method or fields in it. It is simply implemented by class whose objects we may want to serialize.

Moreover serialization is a costly affair because (Taken from Effective Java 2nd edition):

1. **A major cost of implementing Serializable is that it decreases the flexibility
   to change a class’s implementation once it has been released.** When a
   class implements Serializable, its byte-stream encoding (or serialized form)
   becomes part of its exported API. Once you distribute a class widely, you are generally
   required to support the serialized form forever, just as you are required to
   support all other parts of the exported API.
2. **A second cost of implementing Serializable is that it increases the likelihood
   of bugs and security holes.**
3. **A third cost of implementing Serializable is that it increases the testing
   burden associated with releasing a new version of a class.** When a serializable
   class is revised, it is important to check that it is possible to serialize an instance in
   the new release and deserialize it in old releases, and vice versa.

Comment: As you mentioned, "When a class implements Serializable, its byte-stream encoding (or serialized form) becomes part of its exported API", why can't java generate unique byte ordering by looking at .class files? The reason I ask this is, if java can, them attach a .class file and serialize automatically would be possible.(I know giving a .class file would not be good, but at least it's a choice).  It seems to me that there is still some subtle problem in it.

Comment: @Helin Wang: It can and does automatically serialize a class instance by default, but if you then change the class, the new version can't read what the old one wrote. If you handle this yourself, you can put in version numbers or otherwise decode the data in an older version--with some effort.

Answer (score 0):

Serializable is just a marker interface; you don't need to provide any implementation.  Java will provide a reasonable default implementation that works for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Given that one object can reference a bunch of others, serializing that class can get very interesting.  Serializing one object can result in thousands of objects being serialized.  The results can be effortless and brilliant, but 99.9% of the time time you'll want to control and limit at least a portion of the operation.  This is particularly true when you are moving class instances over a socket that is open for the long term.

So labeling a class "Serializable" is states that you have thought through all the ramifications.  These may be trivial or they may be vast and complicated.  But take care:  writing one class instance to a stream **can** result in serializing half the known universe.